# Reliable 'testing' server fails to open XAMPP

Tags: server, xampp, startup

I have had a testing server on my computer for a couple of years. I have been trying to open it today and nothing happens.

I have tried to open my antivirus and added xampp to my allowed applications.

I have XAMPP attached to my toolbar and when I click it to open there is an underline like on the other open programs but I'm not getting the normal screen.

Any help?

Thanks, Bill

Comment: Simplified title for context; minor edits to content for readability

Answer (score 0):

Hello I didn't get any answers but I figured it out on my own and wanted to share the results.

I ended up having to uninstall the original version and reinstall a new one.

Everything works perfect now.

Thanks,
Bill